# migration to azure blob taking indefinite time

Tags: azure, migration

We are enabling `Azure Blob Storage` in `Sitecore 10.2`

As a first step, we are migrating all available media to Azure Blob via PowerShell script.

We tried this on lower environments for testing. However, it is taking so much time. Like 48 hours for 200000 (two hundred thousand) images. This is not acceptable as production will be having more than triple this number.

Is there any better way to migrate the images from Sitecore to an Azure blob?

Comment: What is a lac image? and what size and format are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to increase the pace, we have divided the script into multiple scripts and ran all chunks/batchs in parallel.

Now, we are able to achieve it in 3 hours.

Comment: A more useful answer would be to show how you divided the script, as im sure someone having the same issue in the future might appreciate the information.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately migrating large amounts of content can take alot of time, but there are a few things to consider that might reduce this.

**Cleanup Database**

Over time, a Sitecore solution can accumulate a larger number or unneccessary 'orphaned blobs'. Before migrating your data to blob storage, you should run the  **Database Cleanup** task from within Control Panel on your sitecore solution. In our case, we had approximately 750,000 blobs, accessed by only 55,000 media fields.

**Migration script performance**

Sitecore provides some performance benchmarking, that shows a given VM takes between 44 to 105 minutes to upload approx 16G (660 blobs). Where the script is ran makes a big difference, with locally being fastest, followed by Azure Cloud Shell.

See here for more info https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/blob-storage-performance-reference.html

**Storage Account Tier**

The above benchmarking is based on a Standard tier storage account. If costs allow, you could consider using Premium tier which is much better for high performance workloads. Alternatively, you could do the initial transfer to a premium tier, then do a subsequent copy to standard tier, which might prove faster in long run.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-block-blob-premium

**Request throttling**

We also found that when running the migration scripts, the script would fly through the available blobs to begin with. Then after a given period of time, it would drop down to a snails pace... I believe this was due to the maximum number of http requests being hit on the VM we were using.

One trick we used, was to run the migration script on two separate VMs. But alter the script in the second one, to run in descending order rather than the default ascending order. Then keep monitoring the script and be sure to kill the second script, when you see it getting anywhere near the half way point.

**Finally**

Ultimately though, it does take a long time to send huge amounts of data across the wire. I think when we ran it ourselves, the process lasted several days. The good thing is though, is that you should only need to be doing this one time. Once the data is in blob, and your configs are switched over, you shouldnt need to repeat the process.

I blogged about our experiences delaing with this issue here, which you might also find useful: https://deanobrien.uk/sitecore-reducing-the-size-of-the-master-db/